# Update row based on conditional value

Tags: mysql, case

I have the following tables

```
,--------------------------------------------,
| contacts                                   |
|------------,---------------,---------------|
| contact_id | contact_score | contact_email |
|------------|---------------|---------------|
| 1          | 53            | email1@xx.com |
| 2          | 53            | email2@xx.com |
| 3          | 4             | email3@xx.com |
'------------'---------------'---------------'

,------------------------,
| reputation_email_score |
|---------------,--------,
| email         | score  |
|---------------|--------|
| email1@xx.com | 3      |
| email3@xx.com | 4      |
'---------------'--------'

,----------------------,
| x_message_batch_4_pq |
|----------------------|
| prequeue_contact_id  |
|----------------------|
| 1                    |
| 2                    |
'----------------------'
```

I want to update all scores for contacts who have a score of 53 but only if they are in the `prequeue` table. And if they do not exist in the `reputation` table, they must update to a score of 2.

So in this example:

`contact_score` on `email1@xx.com` would update to `3` and `contact_score` on `email2@xx.com` would update to `2`.

How would I do this? I tried writing a CASE statement, but I am struggling with getting the value from the reputation table.

### EDIT 1

This is what I tried, but I got a `Error in query (1093): You can't specify target table 'x_message_batch_4_pq' for update in FROM clause` error

```
UPDATE x_message_batch_4_pq 
LEFT JOIN contacts ON prequeue_contact_id = contact_id
LEFT JOIN reputation_email_score ON contact_email = email
SET contact_contact_score =
    (CASE WHEN 
        (SELECT COUNT(contact_id) 
        FROM x_message_batch_4_pq 
        JOIN contacts ON prequeue_contact_id = contact_id 
        JOIN reputation_email_score ON contact_email = email 
        WHERE contact_contact_score = '53') = 0
    THEN '2' 
    ELSE (SELECT score FROM reputation_email_score WHERE email = contact_email)
    END)
WHERE contact_contact_score = '53';
```

Comment: What have you tried? update all scores - which column in which table?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to udpate contact_score in table contacts, right?

Comment: Why do you have email in one table and contact_id in another? That way madness lies. :-(

Comment: @SloanThrasher I've updated my question.

Comment: @Strawberry: We have about 301 million emails in our system spread over various dbs. All these emails gets consolidated into one table on another db, which runs various score scripts. This table is unique, and the results of the scores get's pushed back to the various dbs reputation table and then synced back into contacts. The script above saves the score into the contact table if the contact has been added on our system after the last db update ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try use UPDATE statement using JOIN, LEFT JOIN like this

```
UPDATE contacts a 
       JOIN x_message_batch_4_pq b 
         ON a.contact_id = b.prequeue_contact_id 
       LEFT JOIN reputation_email_score c 
              ON a.contact_email = c.email 
SET    a.contact_score = CASE 
                           WHEN c.score IS NULL THEN 2 
                           ELSE c.score 
                         END 
WHERE  a.contact_score = 53
```

I've create a demo [here](http://rextester.com/XKGIT71947), please check

Comment: Will this only update the scores for contacts who have a score of 53?

Comment: Suppose I should add a WHERE at the end of this query with that condition

Comment: Sorry I forgot the condition. I've updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Cool, so this will only update if it exists in prequeue and if it has a score of 53. Going to test now, will report back. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work. I run it and it says 0 rows affected when there are rows that need to change. I've even written tests for it and all of them fail.

Comment: @Albert: If a select on the first two tables based on this answer returns rows, it should match the number affected, even if no changes are made. Unless such a select returns zero rows, this statement should affect rows. Have you tried testing the data using a select like that?

Comment: Sorry, there was an issue on my side. works perfectly